# How can I save data in background service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a local service in my app, when I start the service I set some parameters in it from a activity. When the app is closed those parameters are missing because the service calls its OnCreate method and I need them.

I think I can use SharedPreferences, but Is there another posibility?

Thanks!!

Regards.

Comment: Depends on the kind of data you want to store. Is it enough with storing them in SharedPreferences? Do you need to store them in a DB for further use? Also, why don't you store them in the moment you get them? Is there any reason to not to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I don't like use DB, I have enough with SharedPreferences because the data are three only.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not critical data you should need to reuse in other places, based on your response, I think the best way is storing it in `SharedPreferences`. I recommend you to call `unbindService(your_service)` if your Service is bound, in order to prevent unsafe closing and therefore potential data losing risks. You should save the objects as soon as you get them (if you can), if not, you can set them in the `onDestroy()` method, but keep in mind that `onDestroy` is not always called!